# Why does printf(i) give 0 as output in this program?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=-1;
  !i;
  printf(i);
}
```

**Output:**

> 0

Why is the output **zero**?

Comment: the right command should be `printf("%d", i);`

Comment: Please read a good C book or tutorial!

Comment: suggest reading the man page for each system function call that you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code,

```
 printf(i);
```

is *invalid*, because `printf()` expects a `const char *` as the first argument, and you're passing an `int`. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Turn up the compiler warnings. With the basic level of warning turned on, you should get some message along the line

> warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Solution: I believe, what you *wanted* is

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

Answer (score 2):

First how did that compile ? And even you got an output !!

```
printf(i);
```

Format of printf-    **int printf(const char *format, ...);**

First argument required is `const char*` and you pass a `int`. 
This statement in incorrect. And you would see while compiling with enabled warnings in compiler.

Correct syntax would be -

```
printf("%d",i);
```

And even if you correct your `printf` statement you wont get `0` as output.

```
!i;
```

This should be written as -

```
i=!i;
```

[See here.](https://ideone.com/YDbL4j)